# Flatten a Map<Integer, List<String>> to Map<String, Integer> with stream and lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I would like to flatten a `Map` which associates an `Integer` key to a list of `String`, without losing the key mapping.
I am curious as though it is possible and useful to do so with `stream` and `lambda`.

We start with something like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapFrom = new HashMap<>();
```

Let's assume that mapFrom is populated somewhere, and looks like:

```
1: a,b,c
2: d,e,f
etc.
```

Let's also assume that the values in the lists are unique.

Now, I want to "unfold" it to get a second map like:

```
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
d: 2
e: 2
f: 2
etc.
```

I could do it like this (or very similarly, using `foreach`):

```
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry: mapFrom.entrySet()) {
    for (String s: entry.getValue()) {
        mapTo.put(s, entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Now let's assume that I want to use lambda instead of nested `for` loops. I would probably do something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = mapFrom.entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
    e.getValue().stream().?
    // Here I can iterate on each List, 
    // but my best try would only give me a flat map for each key, 
    // that I wouldn't know how to flatten.
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(/*A String value*/,/*An Integer key*/))
```

I also gave a try to `flatMap`, but I don't think that it is the right way to go, because although it helps me get rid of the dimensionality issue, I lose the key in the process.

In a nutshell, my two questions are :

- Is it possible to use `streams` and `lambda` to achieve this?
- Is is useful (performance, readability) to do so?

Comment: You definitely want `flatMap`: `entrySet.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> new SimpleImmutableEntry(e.getKey(), s))`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that should be an answer

Comment: Very related http://stackoverflow.com/q/34999568/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189147/mapstring-liststring-to-pairstring-string

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap` to flatten the values into a new stream, but since you still need the original keys for collecting into a `Map`, you have to map to a temporary object holding key and value, e.g.

```
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = mapFrom.entrySet().stream()
       .flatMap(e->e.getValue().stream()
                    .map(v->new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), v)))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

The `Map.Entry` is a stand-in for the nonexistent tuple type, any other type capable of holding two objects of different type is sufficient.

An alternative not requiring these temporary objects, is a custom collector:

```
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = mapFrom.entrySet().stream().collect(
    HashMap::new, (m,e)->e.getValue().forEach(v->m.put(v, e.getKey())), Map::putAll);
```

This differs from `toMap` in overwriting duplicate keys silently, whereas `toMap` without a merger function will throw an exception, if there is a duplicate key. Basically, this custom collector is a parallel capable variant of

```
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = new HashMap<>();
mapFrom.forEach((k, l) -> l.forEach(v -> mapTo.put(v, k)));
```

But note that this task wouldn’t benefit from parallel processing, even with a very large input map. Only if there were additional computational intense task within the stream pipeline that could benefit from SMP, there was a chance of getting a benefit from parallel streams. So perhaps, the concise, sequential Collection API solution is preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this informative and complete answer.

Comment: nice answer that covers 360 perspectives :))

Answer (score 9):

You should use `flatMap` as follows:

```
entrySet.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                       .map(s -> new SimpleImmutableEntry(e.getKey(), s)));
```

`SimpleImmutableEntry` is a nested class in `AbstractMap`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick (and good) answer.
Note that there is a missing closing parenthesis at the end.
I would have appreciated an insight on my second question.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this would do it in simplest way. :))

```
mapFrom.forEach((key, values) -> values.forEach(value -> mapTo.put(value, key)));
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Unfortunately, it is not what I was looking for. Maybe I should have made it more clear in the question that I already knew how to do it with `foreach`, and that I wanted to use `stream`.

Comment: @Vongo better you have mentioned that :))

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Please notice that you lost some keys from List.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapFrom = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = mapFrom.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(integerListEntry -> integerListEntry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(listItem -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(listItem, integerListEntry.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Note that we do not lose keys from List in my case, because as I specified in the question, List values are unique (by unique, I meant that there is never a duplicated value between two List, maybe this statement was not clear).
An insight regarding the second question would also have been much appreciated, though!

Answer (score 2):

Same as the previous answers with Java 9:

```
Map<String, Integer> mapTo = mapFrom.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(s -> Map.entry(s, entry.getKey())))
        .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```