# Nested Streams java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Trying to use Java 8 Streams for this

```
 HashMap<String,Games> groupGames = new HashMap<String,Games> ();
 for(Groups group: groups){
    for(int groupId : group.getGroupId){
          groupGames.put(groupId, group.getGame());
    }
 }
```

This works fine but I want to use `java 8` stream to achieve this same functionality.

This is what I have for stream

```
public void toStream(List<Group> group){
    group.stream().map(groups -> groups.getGroupIds())
            .flatMap(group -> groups.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm having hard time putting each of the groupId with the game in the hashmap... 
I'm able to flatten out the list of groupIds

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question, other than "write my code for me"? Did you try a search on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25903137/1531971

Comment: I tried it but I can't seem to do the nested part of it ... heres what I have.

stream().map(groups -> groups.getGroupIds())
    .flatMap(group -> groups.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Comments can be removed. Put relevant details in the question itself. And tell us what you have tried, even referencing other SO Q&A.

Comment: please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484985/flatten-a-mapinteger-liststring-to-mapstring-integer-with-stream-and-lam

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But the linked solution does not handle duplicate `groupId` which can possibly be the case with OP.

Comment: @tsolakp well the linked question does say `whereas toMap without a merger function will throw an exception...`, adding a merge Function is pretty straight-forward anyway

Comment: @Eugene. Just wanted to make sure OP would realize that linked answer does not handle duplicates and will throw exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
 groups.stream()
       .flatMap(x -> x.getGroupId().stream()
                    .map(y -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(y, x.getGame())))
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y));
```

If you *know* there will be no duplicates, you can drop the last argument in `(x,y) -> y`; or you can provide a merge function that you think would be appropriate.

Comment: `Map.entry(y, x.getGame())`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner `@since 9`...