# Gson deserialization skip one quotation

Tags: java, json, spring, gson, pojo

I have to deserialise `JSON`. I use `GSON` library for this purpose. I am building a web application. The user fills up where he wants to fly, then the query is sent to the `API` and the result is returned.

Let us use an example of response:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"WAW":{"0":{"price":153,"airline":"LO","flight_number":678,"departure_at":"2019-08-05T17:40:00Z","return_at":"2019-08-20T14:35:00Z","expires_at":"2019-05-24T20:55:02Z"},"1":{"price":126,"airline":"A3","flight_number":881,"departure_at":"2019-11-21T11:00:00Z","return_at":"2019-11-26T16:05:00Z","expires_at":"2019-05-27T13:39:23Z"},"2":{"price":171,"airline":"KL","flight_number":900,"departure_at":"2019-09-12T02:40:00Z","return_at":"2019-09-18T17:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-05-27T10:40:40Z"},"3":{"price":235,"airline":"B2","flight_number":972,"departure_at":"2019-06-12T07:20:00Z","return_at":"2019-06-18T17:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-05-26T12:31:22Z"},"4":{"price":596,"airline":"TK","flight_number":422,"departure_at":"2019-06-20T00:10:00Z","return_at":"2019-06-24T13:05:00Z","expires_at":"2019-05-26T08:08:21Z"}}},"error":null,"currency":"EUR"}
```

I created a classes in this way: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com

The problem is that there is always the name of the place of arrival. In this case `WAW = Warsaw`.

```
gsonConvert.gson(output).getData().getWAW().getFirst().getAirline()
```

I want to avoid it because the place of arrival will depend on the choice of the user.

Comment: There's no array in your question

Comment: I have corrected , I mean quotation "WAW", and in POJO WAW class

Comment: @bambam can You help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your `data` property to type: `Map<String, Map<String, Flight>>`. Where `Flight` `POJO` represents given flight. Model could look like below:

```
class FlightResponse {

    private boolean success;
    private Map<String, Map<String, Flight>> data;
    private String error;
    private String currency;

    public Map<String, Flight> getFlatData() {
        return data.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(HashMap::new, (m, e) -> m.putAll(e.getValue()), Map::putAll);
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Flight {

    private BigDecimal price;
    private String airline;

    @SerializedName("flight_number")
    private int flightNumber;

    @SerializedName("departure_at")
    private String departureAt;

    @SerializedName("return_at")
    private String returnAt;

    @SerializedName("expires_at")
    private String expiresAt;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

And example how to parse your `JSON`:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        FlightResponse flightResponse = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), FlightResponse.class);

        flightResponse.getFlatData().forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println(k + " => " + v);
        });
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
0 => Flight{price=153, airline='LO', flightNumber=678, departureAt='2019-08-05T17:40:00Z', returnAt='2019-08-20T14:35:00Z', expiresAt='2019-05-24T20:55:02Z'}
1 => Flight{price=126, airline='A3', flightNumber=881, departureAt='2019-11-21T11:00:00Z', returnAt='2019-11-26T16:05:00Z', expiresAt='2019-05-27T13:39:23Z'}
2 => Flight{price=171, airline='KL', flightNumber=900, departureAt='2019-09-12T02:40:00Z', returnAt='2019-09-18T17:30:00Z', expiresAt='2019-05-27T10:40:40Z'}
3 => Flight{price=235, airline='B2', flightNumber=972, departureAt='2019-06-12T07:20:00Z', returnAt='2019-06-18T17:30:00Z', expiresAt='2019-05-26T12:31:22Z'}
4 => Flight{price=596, airline='TK', flightNumber=422, departureAt='2019-06-20T00:10:00Z', returnAt='2019-06-24T13:05:00Z', expiresAt='2019-05-26T08:08:21Z'}
```

See also:

- [Flatten a Map> to Map with stream and lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484985/flatten-a-mapinteger-liststring-to-mapstring-integer-with-stream-and-lam)

Comment: Thank You very much! But I don't still get it how can get only one value. For example price in Flight "0".

Comment: @GrafikKrystian, `getFlatData()` returns [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). So, you can use it's `API` to retrieve all flights. For example: `getFlatData().get("0")`. In case you need all keys use [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) method.To get price of `"0"` key use: `getFlatData().get("0").getPrice()`.

Comment: @GrafikKrystian, also, please, take a look on [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).